# Swift cell content not showing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView that contains cells and each cell should contain an image, a label and a non-editable textView.

Here's what it displays instead: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmOn3.png As you can see it shows an empty tableView but with the three top lines closer to each other.

ViewController.swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

let food = ["Pasta-salad", "Hamburger", "Pancakes"]

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return (food.count)
}
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.foodImage.image = UIImage(named: (food[indexPath.row] + ".jpg"))
    cell.foodLabel.text = food[indexPath.row]
    cell.foodDescription.text = ("insert description of \(food[indexPath.row])")

    return (cell)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

TableViewCell.swift

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var foodImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var foodLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var foodDescription: UITextView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
}
```

Main.storyboard: [image]

Comment: missing delegate or datasource

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the height of cell 0.

Implement the `UITableViewDelegate` method for returning the height of each cell you can also return different height for each, by some calculation.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100.0;//Choose your custom row height
}
```

Comment: Awesome it worked! Thank you, however the images aren't showing, it's just blank where the image should be, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: sure, can you please confirm if the images that you are trying to show exist in your project and are named as 1.jpg, 2,jpg....etc

Comment: Yes look at the image of the Main.storyboard at the bottom of my question, left part of the image shows the images

Comment: Your code and images look fine to me, can you try setting a background colour in the imageview through code to see if the imageview is responding to your actions and is properly connected through iboutlet

Comment: Changing background color of the imageView did work, so why aren't my images working =(

Comment: In that case I think system is unable to find the images to load and display. As I said earlier also that the code looks fine to me, its very hard to guess without actually debugging why isnt it working the way its expected to be. I would suggest printing the uiimage data to see if it contains any value or is nil.

Answer (score 4):

If your cells have a fixed height, set it in `tableView.rowHeight`.

But if you have a dynamic height, check your constraints. It's possible, that you have no constraints related to your cell's bottom.

Also Check **Delegate** and **DataSource**

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your view controller as the tableview's `delegate` and `dataSource`.

Add this to your view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}
```